# How to reset events in an Outlook Add-In

Tags: c#, delegates, outlook, add-in

Working on an Outlook Add-In, so far everything works as expected :
- Addin Loads
- Creates a combobox and Change event handler
- create an event handler for when the users clicks new email

the Add-in depending on what the user selects in the combobox, will load either an HTML template, or a white template ( just to go back to the original state ).

after few tests going back and forth between the two templates, the change event is not caught anymore. as you can see in the code below i use this to handle the change event:

```
cmboBxKeyWord.Change += new CommandBarComboBoxEvents_ChangeEventHandler(cmboBxKeyWord_Change);
```

here is the rest of the code :

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private string templateName = "";
    private string subject="";
    private int messageType;
    private string customerId;
    private CommandBar menuBar;
    private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateControl();

        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    private void CreateControl(){
             menuBar = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar;
            CommandBarComboBox cmboBxKeyWord = (Office.CommandBarComboBox)menuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlComboBox, missing, missing, 1, true);
            cmboBxKeyWord.AddItem("Template Email");
            cmboBxKeyWord.AddItem("Regular Email");
            cmboBxKeyWord.Change += new _CommandBarComboBoxEvents_ChangeEventHandler(cmboBxKeyWord_Change);
    }

    private void cmboBxKeyWord_Change(CommandBarComboBox Ctrl)
    {

       this.messageType = Ctrl.ListIndex - 1;
       if (this.messageType == 1)
       {
           this.templateName = @"c:\templates\Blank Email.txt";
       }
       else
       {
           this.templateName = @"c:\templates\Template Email.txt";
           this.customerId = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Customer ID of the customer to which you want to send this email", "Customer ID");

           if (this.customerId == null || this.customerId.Length == 0)
               this.messageType = 1;
       }
    }

    private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
            {
                if (this.messageType == 0) //HTML template email not the blank email...
                {

                    mailItem.HTMLBody = getBody(); // the get body is a func that returns string, after fetching data from DB and processing it...nothing magic
                    mailItem.Subject = getSubject();
                }
                else
                {
                    mailItem.HTMLBody = "";
                    mailItem.Subject = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm suspecting the event handlers, my idea is the code keeps running and the eventhandlers are always added (+=) never removed (-=) i'm only assuming this because of my little experience with delegates / event handlers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CommandBarComboBox cmboBxKeyWord = (Office.CommandBarComboBox)menuBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlComboBox, missing, missing, 1, true);
```

Combo box needed to be declared outside in the class , it goes out of scope when the procedure is done, and later gets collected by the GC...